# How to make autowrite apply to :make but not to :buffer?

Tags: buffers, save

I have `set autowrite` so that `:make` automatically saved the file before running the build command. But now I'm increasingly using `:buffer` to switch between buffers, and have now noticed that it silently saves the file, unlike `:edit`, to which `autowrite` doesn't apply.

I'd like to have `:make` write the file out, while still having `:buffer` refuse to switch buffers if current file is unsaved (similarly to `:edit`).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: A solution could be to disable `autowrite` and create your own `:Make` command so that it saves the file and execute `:make`. [`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands) should be helpful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `autowrite` and add this to your vimrc, it will save your current modified buffer when you execute `make`:

```
augroup ag_make | au!
  autocmd QuickFixCmdPre make update
augroup end
```

Change `update` to `wa` if you want to save all changed buffers.

> ```
>                                                    *:mak* *:make*
> :mak[e][!] [arguments]  1. All relevant |QuickFixCmdPre| autocommands are
>                        executed.
>                         ...
> ```

Comment: What is the significance of this wrapping with `augroup`? Will bare `autocmd ...` not work?

Comment: @Ruslan bare `autocmd` is dangerous, if you source it twice, it will install autocmd twice.  Wrap it inside `augroup` and call `au!` will make sure only 1 autocmd is installed.

Comment: @Ruslan It get worse if you change sub command, the original `autocmd` still exists when you source the new `autocmd`.

Comment: Hmm, `update` seems to be quite tame to protect in this way...

Comment: @Ruslan It's a habit, a good one, whenever you use `autocmd`, you wrap it in `augroup`,  UltiSnips has an `au` entry for this.